# Jetpack compose mutableState and encapsulation

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, encapsulation

I have seen examples in the android official documentation that exposing property like that

```
var showDialog = mutableStateOf(false)
    private set
```

but i didn't see that properly encapsulates the showDialog var well, so intended for this approach

```
private var _showDialog = mutableStateOf(false)
val showDialog
    get() = _showDialog
```

which approach is much proper and better ?

Comment: `but i didn't see that properly encapsulates the showDialog var well`, how come? The approaches are basically equivalent. The second option is just defining a second useless variable.

Comment: Agree with @marstran, there's no cons here so you should prefer readability.

Comment: this code is in a viewmodel class ,with the first approach ,the exposed property is mutable var and can be altered, the second approach, the exposed property is immutable val and we can't redefine it from outside the class.

Comment: @joghm In the first approach, the setter is private. So it cannot be altered from outside the class. In the second approach, the `_showDialog` is still mutable, so if it changes the `val` will still change value because it re-fetches it every time `get` is called. A `val` is not immutable, it is just read-only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both cases are equivalent here and both are probably wrong/not what you intended. In both cases, caller outside of the class will receive instance of `MutableState<Boolean>` which can be modified using `state.value = x` syntax.

What you've probably seen in documentation is this:

```
var showDialog by mutableStateOf(false)
    private set
```

The only difference is `by` instead of `=`. With that, your `showDialog` property is plain `Boolean` *backed by* `MutableState`. You can still modify it inside the class, but you can't modify it outside of the class because of `private set`. Caller will get plain `Boolean` variable, doesn't have to know there is a `MutableState` behind it, and it is not able to modify it.

Comment: Thank you ,that was helpful,i will add this 
i'm using this to keep the state after process death 

 @OptIn(SavedStateHandleSaveableApi::class)
     var showDialog  by savedStateHandle.saveable {
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }
    private set

Answer (score 1):

By defining **set** as a **private** method, only members of the current class can assign data to the variable and **get** method can be accessed as-usual.

```
class A {
    // readable by everyone
    // writable by only members of the current class
    var a = "a"  
        private set

    // readable & writable by only members of the current class
    private var b = "b"

    // readable & writable by everyone
    var c = "c"
}
```

I prefer using the first one as it is concise and more readable.